# Perl6 hyper » operator doesn't work like map

Tags: raku

As far as I undertand it, the hyper operator `»` is a shortcut for `map()`. Why does the following return two different results and in the second example `.sum` seems not to be applied?

```
say ([1,2], [2, 2], [3, 3]).map({.sum});
# (3 4 6)
say ([1,2], [2, 2], [3, 3])».sum;
# ([1 2] [2 2] [3 3])
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hyperops descend recursively into sublists. Also they are candidates for autothreading (NYI) what means their operations are out of order.

Also there was a bug that is corrected with https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/c8c27e93d618bdea7de3784575d867d9e7a2f6cb .

```
say ([1,2], [2, 2], [3, 3])».sum;
# (3 4 6)
```

Comment: all that is true, but note that hyperoperators do not necessarily descend into substructures (cf `say ([1,2], [2, 2], [3, 3])».elems`); arguably, `List.sum` just lacks an `is nodal` annotation...

Answer (score 7):

**TL;DR** You've almost certainly encountered a bug. That said, `map` and the `»` hyperop have major differences.

`map` returns a [Seq](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Seq). This `Seq` yields the results of applying user supplied code to each of the elements of a user supplied data structure:

- one level deep (traversal of the data structure is shallow -- `map` doesn't recursively descend in to sub structures of the data structure's top level)
- one at a time (everything is done sequentially, nothing in parallel)
- lazily (`map` returns immediately; the user supplied code is applied to the user supplied data structure to generate results later as needed to pull values from the `Seq`)

The `»` hyperop returns the data structure operand on its left after first applying the unary operation on its right to the elements of that data structure:

- only one level deep *or* descending to [leaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29#Leaf) *as dictated by the unary operation*
- in parallel batches, at least semantically (it's the programmer's responsibility to pick an unary operation that will yield correct results when applied to multiple elements in parallel in arbitrary order)
- eagerly (unlike a `map` call, a hyperoperation only returns when the unary operator has been applied to the entire data structure)

If you're applying an unary operator that is ["nodal"](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/is%20nodal) (so hyperoperation will choose not to descend) *or* the data structure being operated on is only one level deep (so there are no lower level leaves for the hyperoperation to descend to) then the differences between hyperoperation and `map` with an unary operator are just the sequential/parallel and lazy/eager aspects.

It seems pretty clear to me that `sum` ought to be a nodal operator otherwise it will descend in to sub structures until it arrives at individual leaves and will thus end up being applied to a bunch of single values which is pointless. *ETA:* Looks like it's fixed now.