# How can I idiomatically ignore undefined array elements (or avoid assigning them to an array in the first place)?

Tags: raku

If you assign an undefined value to an array, it will contain that undefined value, which complicates using loops if you don't want to iterate over undefined values:

```
my @bar = 1, 2, Any;

for @bar -> $baz {
    put $baz;
}
```

This gives the following output, including a warning for the undefined values:

> ```
> 1
> 2
> Use of uninitialized value $baz of type Any in string context.
> Methods .^name, .perl, .gist, or .say can be used to stringify it to something meaningful.
>   in block  at for.p6 line 4
> ```

I know that I can deal with this explicitly in a number of way, for example:

```
for @bar -> $baz {
    next unless $baz; # Skip this iteration
    put $baz;
}

for @bar.grep: *.defined {    # Just iterate over the defined values
    put $baz;
}

# Reassign @bar to only contain defined values
@bar.=grep(*.defined);
for @bar -> $baz {
    put $baz;
}
```

But, isn't there a more idiomatic way to avoid `@foo` receiving undefined values or to avoid iterating over undefined values?

---

For the time being, when assigning to an array, I'm going to be using the following `defined-flat` function to avoid these situations:

```
multi defined-flat (@array) {
    return @array.grep(*.defined).flat;
}

# Return single defined element (or empty list for single undefined value)
multi defined-flat ($element) {
    return $element // ();
}
```

Comment: "or avoid assigning them to an array in the first place" -- That really depends on how you're constructing the array. The most idiomatic solution would probably be to generate the input data for the array in such a way that it only contains the intended elements and no uninitialized "dead" elements.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`duckmap`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/duckmap)

```perl6
my @bar = 1, 2, Any;

@bar.duckmap: -> Mu:D $baz {
    put $baz;
}
```

```perl6
duckmap -> Mu:D $baz {
    put $baz;
}, @bar;
```

```perl6
# the “:” makes this a method call
duckmap @bar: -> Mu:D $baz {
    put $baz;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Also sometimes handy is the [with](https://docs.perl6.org/language/control#with,_orwith,_without) statement, which both topicalizes and tests for definedness:

```
my @bar = 1, 2, Any;

for @bar -> $baz {
    put $_ with $baz
}
```

Or:

```
my @bar = 1, 2, Any;

for @bar {
    with $_ -> $baz {
        put $baz;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! `with` is very useful. I'm going to start using it.

Answer (score 4):

You also can try to use `map` to solve the problem:

```
my @a = [0, 1, 2, 3, Any].map({ $_ if $_.defined });
```

Or with `race` to enable multi-threads:

```
my @a = [0, 1, 2, 3, Any].race.map({ $_ if $_.defined });
```

Or `>>.`:

```
my @a = [0, 1, 2, 3, Any]>>.&({ $_ if $_.defined });
```

I prefer the last one :p

Comment: Interesting. Is `>>.&` effectively a synonym for `map`, or is there more to it?

Comment: Here comes the differences: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38806794/8517446

Answer (score 3):

You could just `grep` for defined items

```
for @bar.grep(*.defined) -> $bar {
    say $bar;
}
```

Of course, undefined values are *Falsy* so you can just grep for the *Truthy* ones if you want something shorter (but less explicit, IMO)

```
for @bar.grep(&so) -> $bar {
    say $bar;
}
```

FWIW, Only the second one ignores the empty list given: `my @bar = [(1,2), (3,4), (), (7,8)];`

Comment: Interesting. The second one also ignores `0`, but if I weren't expecting `0` then that would definitely work.

Comment: Thanks. I never realized that I could use `@bar.grep(&so)`. I wonder why `@bar.grep(&defined)` doesn't work.

Comment: Not being able to use [`@bar.grep(&defined)` is a bug](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=128905).

Answer (score 2):

If your real problem is a single undefined element getting assigned to an array, then adding defined-or `//` followed by an empty list `()` or `Empty` to create an empty array in those situations:

```
> my @bar =  Any;
[(Any)]
> my @bar =  Any  // ();
[]
> my @bar = (Any) // ();
[]
> my @bar =  Any  // Empty;
[]
my @bar   = (Any) // Empty;
[]
```

An empty array will not be iterated over and thus `for @bar -> $baz {}` would not be evaluated for a single iteration.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the idiomatic way is, but this one works without hassle:

```
Perl6:

> my @a = [Any,1,2,3]
> grep { !($_.WHAT === Any) }, @a
> (1 2 3)
```

As always with the Perl world, there is more than one way to do stuff...